# How does findById and similar methods work in Spring?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

These days i am trying to learn internal processing of JPA and Spring.

I have a confusion regarding Repository functions like `findById()`, `findNameById()` etc.

1. How do these functions work, do they hit database on each call? 
   Lets say, if following is implemented

   `for(loop 1million ids) {SomeRepo.findById(Long Id);}`

Will database be hit 1 million times?

2. And if `@Query` is used for simple database call, lets say to get ids on the basis of name, how will it work with respect to db call and processing?

Comment: "These days i am trying to learn internal processing of JPA and Spring" - okay, but I would leave spring-data out of it for now. Focus on the fundamentals of JPA first.

Comment: Yes, My focus right now is JPA, Can you please recommend any websites or blogs which i should see on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a db call in a `for` cycle, it will hit db 1 million times, a framework cannot avoid that, unless you use a cache.
Instead to use `for(loop 1million ids){ SomeRepo.findById(Long Id);}`

You should use `findByIdIn(List<long> ids)` and make a single db call (using ids pagination if necessary)

`@Query` do the same things , you can use what you like but it can happen a method name is too long example:

```
List<Person> findByPersonAddressNameAndPersonAddressNumberOrderByPersonAddressNameDesc(String addressName, Long addressNumber)
```

and in this case you can choose a shorten name for your method with query annotation

```
  @Query(from Person where person.address.name = :name and person.address.number = :number order by person.address.number desc);
  public List<Person> findByAddressAndNumber(String name, Long number)
```

Comment: In second question i mean, writing a query to get name by using @Query annotation, how will it work? Want to ask for both questions, will jpa/Spring not work on proxy objects? I read somewhere that for these methods Spring uses proxy objects, though they didnt give much explanation to this.

Comment: To clarify, findById will not query the database if the object is already loaded into the current EntityManager, for example when our code is already inside a @Transactional context.